# how to test a failed charge using stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am testing using stripe and node.

- A customer has inputted a credit card as a payment method

How am I able to simulate a failed charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe provides a couple card numbers to test all possibilities.

Please refer to this page: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments

You'll be able to choose the card number you'd need for the test you are trying to accomplish.

```
Generic decline             4000000000000002    
Insufficient funds decline  4000000000009995    
Lost card decline           4000000000009987    
Stolen card decline         4000000000009979    
Expired card decline        4000000000000069    
Incorrect CVC decline       4000000000000127    
Processing error decline    4000000000000119    
Incorrect number decline    4242424242424241
```

Comment: I cannot simulate a charge on these card numbers because it won't even allow me to add these cards as payment methods to begin with. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a test api key?